# simple way of converting ASCII into HEX with no change in value

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the easiest way of converting a ASCII-String into hex without changing the value?

what i have:

```
string = "00FA0086"
```

what i want:

```
hex_string = b'\x00\xFA\x00\x86"
```

Is there a simple way or do i need to write a function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: The first thing i tried till now is the decode function with this: `decode(string, 'hex_codec')` but this will give me not the same value it will just look up what as example "FA" has as hex-value. I was just looking for a build-in function in python to get me "what i want". If there arent any, i'm going to write something, but i would recommend to have a clean built-in function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `binascii` module from the Standard Python Library:

```
import binascii

string = "00FA0086"

print(repr(binascii.a2b_hex(string)))
```

gives:

```
b'\x00\xfa\x00\x86'
```

Comment: Yeah, thank u very much! This was what i was looking for

Comment: when i want to convert a bigger string like ''00009e0890423374'' i get something like b'\x00\x00\x9e\x08\x90B3t'. Is there a other function for longer strings like this one?

Comment: @tryanderror: 0x42 is ascii code for `B`, 0x33 for `3` and 0x74 for `t`, hence the result. The representation of a byte representing an ascii character is that character.